# How to configure angular ui-router state that will match any and all present query parameters?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

## The Problem:

I'd like a single ui-router state to match the following urls:

```
#/.../update?id
#/.../update?username
#/.../update?customerId&sandwichId
```

If/when the 'update' state is active (it's a routed component), the component's controller knows enough to expect which params will be there (via a provided array of Strings that should/will match whatever query params are in fact present).

## Current Solutions (none of which I'm 100% happy with)

I could just leave the url at '#/.../update' with the implicit understanding that I cannot navigate to that url from anywhere but it's parent state, and just pass in its primary key fields as a component binding.  The drawback obviously being if I just type the URL in my browser, it will not have enough information to load.

As per an example I found [here](http://webslainte.blogspot.com/2014/05/angularjs-ui-router-query-string.html), I defined my 'update' state with single query parameter: pkKeys.  I then define pkKeys upon my state transition to be the entire query parameter string I desire.  This effectively achieves what I am looking for.  However, typing this just doesn't feel right:

```
#/.../update?pkKeys=username=test
```

Moreover, it looks ugly on the more complicated situations:

```
#/.../update?pkKeys=customerId%3D3ae2e6eb-3bf7-42f8-a09c-9c690c8dbe15%26sandwichId%3D2cb6d513-06a3-4aa4-93bb-e53d279d95cb
```

## Ideal Target State

Ideally, I'm looking for a way to configure my state in a way that matches the above patterns of urls.  I did not have much success with $location service, but something tells me that has something to do with it.  It appeared to me that $location.search() was cleared whenever $state.go( ... ) was invoked.

Thanks for any help in advance!  Happy to elaborate on anything that might not be clear.  It's a rather unique problem set I find myself in here...

## On Further Research

For reference, I'm using Angular UI Router 1.x.  I have found they have the notion of dynamic parameters, which seems to nearly solve the problem I am encountering (see the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/202) for this change).  However, where this fails me is the state configuration still expects you to list the dynamic parameter's name.  As my query param names are data-driven, the set of names is not a finite set.  So I need dynamic parameters...with dynamic names.

Comment: **In case anyone stumbles here with the same problem...** Raised this question as a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3038) as well.  Received as a response that "wildcard search parameters" are not supported, though that functionality is up for consideration, just not yet prioritized.  Leaving this question open for now in case someone comes up with a clever solution, but personally will be staying with my current, non-ideal workaround for now.